# I have to restart my printer for every next print

Tags: printing, xerox

I have a problem with Xerox Phaser 3140 and Ubuntu 14.10. The first printing for the day is ok, but if I have to print something else few minutes later, I have to stop and push out my printer again otherwise It doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem with Canon printer MF3010 on Ubuntu 16.04